# What is the Lebesgue measure of a following set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This might be trivial for some of you.
Let $E$ be a set defined by $ E= \{(x,y):   a<\frac{x}{y}<b, c<\frac{y}{x}<d  \}$. What is the Lebesgue measure of this set. Measure should be an area. But I am having hard time visualizing this.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Maybe it would help to consider $\{(x,y):a < x/y < b\}$ and $\{(x,y):c < y/x < d\}$ separately, and then take the intersection?

Comment: thanks. Yes, this is what I am thinking but what is the intersection? This is my problem I can't see it.

Comment: Rewrite the inequalities: $ay<x<by$ and $cx<y<dx$. Now think of a quadrilateral formed by four straight lines.

Comment: @user46944  so you think this might not be measurable? Can you explain?

Comment: @user63050 It seems I was a bit misleading when I mentioned the quadrilateral. Apologies for any confusion!

Comment: @useer46944 I see. I think you just made my life more complicated. I kind of assumed that it's measurable. Because of the simple constrains. Can you give me an example, maybe values of a,b,c,d for which it's not measurable?

Comment: @user63050 Sorry!  I didn't mean to complicate things.  I'm deleting my comments because I don't think they are useful.  I'm still a beginner in this material.  The first thought that popped into my head was about whether or not this set is even measurable, and I don't know how to show that it is.

Comment: @Bhoot: You can't rewrite the inequalities that way unless you assume that both $x$ and $y$ are positive.

Comment: So, it's not just me. This problem has a lot of special cases, right?

Answer (score 1):

Picture (in a case where $0 < a < b, 0 < c < d$):

[image]

Comment: In this case it has infinite measure, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @RobertIsrael How do we know the set $E$ is measurable?  I don't know how to show it.

Comment: All open sets are measurable.